# jQuery - Rewrite various strings to look correct

Tags: jquery

I may have a link formated with the following text in these 3 flavors, on my custom page...

```
<h3 class="ms-srch-ellipsis"><a class="ms-srch-item-link" href="...">this_old_house_is_broken</a></h3>
<h3 class="ms-srch-ellipsis"><a class="ms-srch-item-link" href="...">this-old-house-is-broken</a></h3>
<h3 class="ms-srch-ellipsis"><a class="ms-srch-item-link" href="...">ThisOldHouseIsBroken</a></h3>
```

What is a best practice approach with jQuery, to check all ms-srch-ellipsis elements and fix the text to look like this...

```
<h3 class="ms-srch-ellipsis"><a href="...">This Old House Is Broken</a></h3>
```

I started with this approach, just to get somewhere...but it doesn't change anything...

```
$( ".ms-srch-item-link" ).each(function(e) {
  $(this).text().replace('-',/\s+/g);       
    $(this).text().replace('_',/\s+/g);     
});
```

Comment: `text()` accepts the argument that must be set. `.text('foo')` will set it to `foo`.

Comment: ....you mean I have to put the condition inside the brackets as upose to the right of it?

Comment: Condition? What condition?

Comment: To change the text you must pass a value as a `.text()` function argument, like `.text(new_value)`. When you simply call `.text()` without arguments it just returns the current value, nothing more

Comment: You'll have to capture the result of `.replace()`. It doesn't modify the text itself. `$(this).text($(this).text().replace('-',/\s+/g));`

Comment: it works, I'm just not using the right replace code for empty space...

Comment: You can also pass a function to text() that takes the text content and returns the modified version: http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function

Comment: This answer may help you write the replace expression: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662936/using-replace-and-regex-to-capitalize-first-letter-of-each-word-of-a-string-in-j

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".ms-srch-item-link" ).each(function(e) {
  $(this).text().replace(function(i, text) { // apply replacement function
    return text.charAt(0).toUpperCase +      // capitalize first letter
           text.substring(1).
             replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, function(m, g1, g2) { // camel case
               return g1 + " " + g2;
             }).
             replace(/(_|-)([a-z])/g, function(m, g1, g2) { // dash/underscore
               return " " + g2.toUpperCase();
             });

  });
});
```